# how to disable gradle build scan permanently?

Tags: java, gradle

I know I can add `--no-scan` on an individual command line (see https://docs.gradle.com/build-scan-plugin/), but I'm looking for a way to disable this in `build.gradle`, `gradle.properties` or `settings.gradle` so i dont have to always type it or set an alias.

Any Ideas on how that can be done?

Comment: Isn't that generally an opt-in feature? Is it an option to simply not apply the plugin for buildscans?

Comment: Look in your build.gradle, do you have something like `plugins { id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version 'x.y' }`?

Comment: its normally opt-in, but sadly in my case the scan is turned on by a mandated, company-wide plugin. its not in my project's build.gradle (at least not directly) and i cannot disable the plugin that sets it

Answer (score 4):

You can edit your `hosts` file on your computer and place the entry where it is sending the reports to `127.0.0.1`. It will print some errors after every build, but that is all.

Another possibility is to add `--no-scan` to `gradle` command or wrapper script.

Comment: +1 to the `/etc/hosts` idea because i had some ghost setting sitting around on a 4.10 version of gradle that no one could help me track down. so i did that and now at least i'm up and running again!

Answer (score 2):

You can query gradle parameters (tasks, flags...etc.) through [StartParameter](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html) and fail a build early if it runs with `--scan` flag as reported by [StartParameter.isBuildScan()](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#isBuildScan-).

The release of Gradle is not specified in the question and that API is available since Gradle 3.1. I believe it was incubating until Gradle 5.X.

```groovy
if (gradle.startParameter.isBuildScan()) {
    throw new GradleException("you shall not scan")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your main `build.gradle` file (groovy):

```
buildScan {
  server = 'https://gradle-build-scan-disabled'
}
```

Now, any attempt to run a `--scan` will result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the option "Modify run configuration" in the "Build" tab in the bottom navigation, then simply change the command in Run and click Apply. After that, restart Android studio [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEXgt.png)